# Trying to read back binary data from a file, causing crash

Tags: c, file, io, binary, fread

thanks in advance for your help.

I'm trying to call a function which will read back date from the binary file I've just created of a sine wave. The file has already been opened in w+b in the main function. I want to copy the data to my buffer array, then print them out.

end_time is the total number of samples in the file. The samples have been written as floats. Code Blocks gives no errors, but the program crashes when it gets to this point and I'm not sure why.

```
void printwave(FILE *fp, int end_time)
{
   int i;

   float buffer[end_time];
   fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);


   for(i=0; i==end_time; i++)
   {
        fread(buffer, sizeof(float), 1, fp);
        printf("%d\t%.2f\n", i, buffer[i]);
   }

}
```

Thanks for your help,
Andy.

Comment: The 'for' condition is wrong. It should be i < end_time.

Comment: the posted code (if the `for()` statement is corrected) reads the whole file into the buffer[] array.  Which is completely unnecessary.   Much better to, in a loop, read one float, printf one float, etc

Comment: when calling the function `fread()`, check the returned value (in this case the value should be 1) to assure the operation was successful.   when calling the function `fseek()`, check the returned value (in this case the value should be 0) to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is in your code, you read one element after the end of `buffer`. Because valid elements have indices from `0` to `end_time - 1` so the immediate fix to your code is

```
while ((i < end_time) && (fread(buffer, sizeof(float), 1, fp) == 1))
{
    printf("%d\t%.2f\n", i, buffer[i]);
    i += 1;
}
```

---

Note: Don't try `printf("%d\t%.2f\n", i, buffer[i++]);` or similar because it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Turns out the crash was caused by the array, it was too big.
I now have an array with only one value stored at a time, with fread back in the loop. Works fine up until the 4096th sample, where it just hangs at whatever value is in the 4095th. Any ideas?

Comment: Why `fread()` back in the loop? you MUST CHECK IT'S RETURN VALUE. Maybe the stack is too small on your platform.

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `fread()` needs to be checked to make sure there is no error

For loops's condition should be `i < end_time`

It seems the file is being opened in write mode, but both reading and writing are done.

Return value of `fseek` needs to be checked as well. I am assuming that `fp` is a valid file pointer and its validity has already been checked when the file was opened.

Since you are reading each float  and printing out, you may not need to store it in an array buffer.